# Animation Transition Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to transition a game object to an existing animation?

Currently I have a cube object like this:

[image]

The cube Object has a **preconfigured simple jumping animation with fixed location** as *Layer default state*. Lets call this animation: "**BoxJumping**".

The player however can move the cube object to any position(using wsad) key.
When the player stop for 1 sec, I want the cube to transition back to the original position of the animation. Like this:

[image: y]

I can simply use:

```
private void playJumpAnim()
{
   gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("BoxJumping");
}
```

However, it just directly move the cube to the preconfigure location which has been stored in the animation and play the animation without any **smoothing transtion**.

Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of transition?

Comment: You could try to take the preconfigured position from the animation and move your box slowly until it reaches that position, before starting the animation again. I don't know enough about the animations in unity to tell you how to get that position though. Look up the documentation for that.

Comment: The Animator Component is one of the worst designed things in all game engines. Nothing about it is intuitive, most of it is not what it even is named. Avoid it if you can, use Legacy Animation components and clips.

Comment: Check out CrossFade `gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().CrossFade("BoxJumping", overThisTime);`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is create an empty gameobject to be parent of the cube. When the [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html) is a child, it performs the updates on local space.

Then you can move the cube by the parent gameobject.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works with one object. However, if there are more than one object, says 100 different kind of game object, it will be quite painfull to add them. (｡•́︿•̀｡)

do you have any other suggestion?